# How to bypass pyqtgraph's built-in methods?

Tags: user-interface, plot, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to plot a grid of squares given in the following format
{'p0a0': [[1255.1929931640625, 1430.1819458007812, 1428.170166015625, 1253.1811828613281, 1255.1929931640625], [407.78900146484375, 409.629638671875, 600.617431640625, 598.7767791748047, 407.78900146484375]], 'p0a1': ....} [and once plotted it should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEykk.png)
I'm trying to pyqtgraph.PlotDataItem.setData() method. My idea was to use a for loop to iterate over all the keys in the dictionary and plot all the grid points (squares) in the same plot but, the setData() method inherently any clears previous data before plotting. Resulting in giving me the following output [only one square is highlighted instead of all 64 squares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52b6b.png)
So, my question is how do I bypass the built-in resting when I call .setData() method? or If that can't be done, would anyone have a suggestion to go arround it?

I tryed giving the whole dictionary but, it didn't work. also I tried other ploting items but, couldn't find anything that works for my requiremnts.

Comment: Create new plotDataItem for each square.

Comment: As lufsasc says, you can create multiple plotitems, one for each square, and add each of them to the plot. This makes the most sense because each square can have a different pen color and you can turn them on/off individually by adding/removing from the plot.